# Migrating from asp to asp.net - What are classic ado's recordset 'replacements'?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, asp-classic, ado

I've tried to do my homework on this...

I'm migrating a site from **classic asp** to **asp.net 4.0**

Before I rework all the code, I wanted to get clarification that the way *i think* my database code should be updated is fairly correct.  (I'm using **SQLClient** objects)

First, when old code would use forward only recordsets or access single record/value, I'm fairly sure i'd use **SqlCommand** and **SqlDataReader**.  That is pretty straightforward.

Now, when my old code navigates a recordset (movePrevious, find, etc.)...  I believe the way to go is with **SqlDataAdapter** and **DataTable** to retrieve the data and **DataView** to filter/find/navigate the data.

I'n looking to do a quick migration... i don't want to get too bogged down in the new entity framework... so - just trying to stick with similar objects/logic.

I know this is one of those questions that doesn't really have a right/wrong answer... and I think that is part of my problem in finding an answer - there are so many.

Thanks,

bill g

Comment: Forget the quick migration, you going to rewrite many thinks.

Comment: Was my answer good enough, bill g? I'm guessing it probably wasn't what you wanted to hear but I think it'd be a good opportunity for you to build on your skillset and build something maintainable in the long run.

Comment: well - the key to my question is 'quick migration.'  I have no intention _at this time_ to redesign the thing.  So - I'm updating the code to be compliant - pretty much line by line.  What I am working from is (my own) poorly written app full of sql and recordsets.  Anyway, my goal is to move this monster to asp.net (to resolve some speed issues) and then redesign/rewrite.  So - I just want verify the parallels in .net 4 to recordsets.

Comment: Why do you think this is the solution to speed issues?  Also, if you want to move from ASP to .Net and you WANT to do a line by line port - move to WebMatrix WebPages approach.  You get C# compiling, you keep the mix of html and server side code the same. You don't need to use WebMatrix, you can use visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

I answered something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5293553/asp-net-c-form-submit-can-my-function-be-shorter-and-faster/5293821#5293821).

You only really need to know about the database bit [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664408%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx). For you it's a really good point to start as you mean to go on.

It terms of how deal with the data returned, it's up to you. I'd recommend custom class style dataset approach which will make life easier in the long run but of course in the short term, you'll have to generate them all which can be made easier by [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/)*. That in itself has an upfront cost but will, again, save time in the long run.

*Other code generation tools are available.

Answer (score 0):

If your main issue is the database I propose to move and learn the Subsonic 2 (not [subsonic 3, too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363735/benchmark-linq2sql-subsonic2-subsonic3-any-other-ideas-to-make-them-faster)) or any other DAL.

See here some examples: 
http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page

Take some time to understand it, make some tests, see what really do, after wille you can't do with out it, but you need some time to understand the logic, and setup it to your project.

Get [this project](http://www.planethost.gr/DalSpeedTests.rar) to play with and see some dal in action, ready to run.